# Can you upload non-SSRS files to SSRS Server with Powershell?

Tags: reporting-services

SQL Server 2019.  In the SSRS Report Server web interface I can upload any file, Pdf, Excel, Word, etc.  I've got a lot of files I want to upload and the web interface only allows me to do one at a time.  Can I upload all files in a folder to the SSRS server using Powershell?  So far what I've found only seems to work for SSRS files - rdl, rsd, etc.  Is there some other way to upload multiple non-SSRS files?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below PowerShell script, you will need to change the folder location and the report server URL as well as the -RSFolder reference. The script will upload all files within the folder. Please be aware that SSRS does restrict some file types, these can be found using the following SQL code :

```
SELECT ConfigInfoID
      ,Name
      ,Value
  FROM ReportServer.dbo.ConfigurationInfo
  WHERE Name = 'AllowedResourceExtensionsForUpload'
```

-- PowerShell Script --

```
$FileLocation = "C:\Files\"
$Files = Get-ChildItem $FileLocation

foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    Write-RSRestCatalogItem -Overwrite -ReportPortalUri http://ReportServer/Reports/ -Path $Files.FullName -RsFolder "Files" -RestApiVersion V1.0
}
```

Comment: WOW!  That works!!  I think part of the problem I had was when I tried this before I hadn't updated the allowed file types.  I did modify that in the report server properties but never tried this again.  Thanks very much for replying!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Also should have mentioned that you need to install a PowerShell module:

Install-Module -Name ReportingServicesTools